# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED when making API calls to my backend from React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I'm having issues with React.js making API calls.
I'm building this mini social app that interacts with a a node.js backend.

But my React server always crashes when I make the second API call, the first one works perfectly, but the second one fails. The chrome browser shows internet disconnected while the second one says

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

> AxiosError

Comment: Please add some code snippets to understand what are you doing.

Comment: I think its happened cos I added an image when making posts and the image has a size of 2mb, can such crash the server?

Comment: I don't know the way you are sending the image, that is why I'm asking for some code snippets, you can try with a smaller image, to check if still failing and discard that theory